# File Permissions crashing DNS/Internet on Chrome (error 1014)

Tags: google-chrome, dns, permissions, microsoft-edge, wpad

My internet keeps crashing when I use Chrome (and several other programs). I can use Microsoft Edge without any problems and this problem is unique to this one computer. None of the usual solutions to Error 1014 like uninstalling and so on work. It tries to establish connection but fails. I think that it might have something to do with File Permissions as Edge is located in my Windows folder while Chrome and the other programs with problems are located in Program Files. And somehow this is crashing my internet connection - I added some permissions (I don't remember what exactly) to an Adobe folder and it couldn't connect but when I through guesswork changed it back it worked again. Here is the Adobe error:

> Log Name:      System Source:        Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client
>   Date:          7/6/2018 5:41:27 PM Event ID:      1014 Task Category:
>   (1014) Level:         Warning Keywords:      (268435456) User:
>   NETWORK SERVICE Computer:      DESKTOP-0N1E8LK Description: Name
>   resolution for the name wpad timed out after none of the configured
>   DNS servers responded. Event Xml: 
>   
>       
>       1014
>       0
>       3
>       1014
>       0
>       0x4000000010000000
>       
>       21617
>       
>       
>       System
>       DESKTOP-0N1E8LK
>             
>       wpad
>       128
>       02000000C0A80101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Here is an error for Chrome that I cant fix.

> - System
>
>   - Provider            [ Name]     Microsoft-Windows-DNS-Client            [ Guid]     {1C95126E-7EEA-49A9-A3FE-A378B03DDB4D}
>
>     EventID 1014
>
>     Version 0
>
>     Level   3
>
>     Task    1014
>
>     Opcode  0
>
>     Keywords    0x4000000010000000
>   - TimeCreated             [ SystemTime]   2018-06-26T20:00:56.935162900Z
>
>     EventRecordID   19853
>
>     Correlation
>   - Execution           [ ProcessID]    2520            [ ThreadID]     28844
>
>     Channel System
>
>     Computer    DESKTOP-0N1E8LK
>   - Security            [ UserID]   S-1-5-20
> - EventData       QueryName   cdn.content.prod.cms.msn.com
>
>   AddressLength   128
>       Address 02000000C0A80101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Is giving Full Control to a group crashing my internet? What should be the correct configuration?

Comment: “I think that it might have something to do with File Permissions as Edge is located in my Windows folder while Chrome and the other programs with problems are located in Program Files.” Why do you believe that is related?

Comment: because edge works and chrome doesn't and because changing adobe permissions (adding them not getting rid of any) coincided with problems that disappeared when I tinkered with permissions with the folder adobe was in. But its just a hunch.

Comment: Anyone have an explanation what the errors above mean in a technical sense?